# error : The method getFilter() is undefined for the type FriendsActivity.ListAdapter

Tags: android

Trying to implement search functionality in list view having problem in search,here i am placing code where i am getting error

```
 friendsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the Text
                    FriendsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                    //*in the above line i am getting error.*
       }

         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: is adapter an instance of ArrayAdapter or SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: instance of array adapter.

Comment: question name is the error

Comment: ListAdapter does not define getFilter. You should use ArrayAdapter or SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: is it possible for search option if i continue with list adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `FriendsActivity.this.adapter` has type `ListAdapter`. If it's actually array adapter then try:

```
((ArrayAdapter<?>) FriendsActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(cs)
```

**EDIT:**

You have following class: `class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter` in your sources. BaseAdapter doesn't implement filter. So you need to implement it manually. Check this tutorial: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html

Comment: @user1987430 `ListAdapter` is an interface. What is actual class?

Comment: @user1987430 What does `FriendsActivity.this.adapter.getClass()` returns?

Comment: is it possible for search option if i continue with list adapter?

Comment: it returns list items dynamically.

Comment: @user1987430 `ListAdapter` is just an interface. It's possible that actual class is `ArrayAdapter` or some other adapter that has `getFilter` method. So you should check what is actual class of adapter.

Comment: @user1987430 show where you initialize `FriendsActivity.this.adapter`. Edit your question and post more code to it.

Comment: @user1987430 I've updated my answer with tutorial that shows how to implement filter manually.